# GroovyScriptEngine throws MultipleCompilationErrorsException while loading class that uses other class' static inner class

Tags: groovy

I'm running into a problem with GroovyScriptEngine - it seems not to be able to work with inner classes.  Anyone know whether there's some limitation in GroovyScriptEngine or a workaround?

I have a directory with these two files:

```groovy
// MyClass.groovy

public class MyClass {
    MyOuter m1;
    MyOuter.MyInner m2;
}
```

and

```groovy
// MyOuter.groovy

public class MyOuter {
    public static class MyInner {}
}
```

I have a following test class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine;

public class TestGroovyScriptEngine {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        final File myGroovySourceDir = new File("C:/MyGroovySourceDir");

        final URL[] urls = { myGroovySourceDir.toURL() };
        GroovyScriptEngine groovyScriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngine(urls,
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        Class<?> clazz = groovyScriptEngine.getGroovyClassLoader().loadClass("MyClass");
    }

}
```

When I run it I get the following compilation error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\MyGroovySourceDir\MyClass.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class MyOuter.MyInner 
 @ line 3, column 2.
    MyOuter.MyInner m2;
    ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:311)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:983)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:633)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:582)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:354)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:87)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:320)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:318)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyScriptEngine.java:248)
    at groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine$ScriptClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyScriptEngine.java:235)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:307)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:811)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:767)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:836)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:824)
```

I would have expected a "clean compile", but the inner class seems to be causing problems.

My groovy classes compile fine at the command line using groovyc, or in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have faced an edge case here. To clarify what happens let's define the initial conditions:

- you have a Java (or Groovy) class that gets executed inside JVM
- you have two Groovy classes that get loaded outside of the JVM

The problem you have described does not exist if you put these two Groovy classes inside the same path you execute your Java class from - in this case IDE takes care to compile these Groovy classes and put them to the classpath of a JVM that gets started to run your Java test class.

But this is not your case and you are trying to load these two Groovy classes outside the running JVM using `GroovyClassLoader` (which extends `URLClassLoader` btw). I will try to explain in the simplest possible words what happened that adding field of type `MyOuter` does not throw any compilation error, but `MyOuter.MyInner` does.

When you execute:

```
Class<?> clazz = groovyScriptEngine.getGroovyClassLoader().loadClass("MyClass");
```

Groovy class loader goes to script file lookup part, because it was not able to find `MyClass` in the current classpath. This is the part responsible for it:

```
    // at this point the loading from a parent loader failed
    // and we want to recompile if needed.
    if (lookupScriptFiles) {
        // try groovy file
        try {
            // check if recompilation already happened.
            final Class classCacheEntry = getClassCacheEntry(name);
            if (classCacheEntry != cls) return classCacheEntry;
            URL source = resourceLoader.loadGroovySource(name);
            // if recompilation fails, we want cls==null
            Class oldClass = cls;
            cls = null;
            cls = recompile(source, name, oldClass);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            last = new ClassNotFoundException("IOException while opening groovy source: " + name, ioe);
        } finally {
            if (cls == null) {
                removeClassCacheEntry(name);
            } else {
                setClassCacheEntry(cls);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Source: [src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java#L733-L753](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java#L733-L753)

Here `URL source = resourceLoader.loadGroovySource(name);` it loads the full file URL to the source file and here `cls = recompile(source, name, oldClass);` it executes class compilation.

There are several [phases](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/Phases.java) involved in Groovy class compilation. One of them is `Phase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS` which analyses class fields and their types for instance. At this point `ClassCodeVisitorSupport` [executes `visitClass(ClassNode node)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java#L49-L55) for `MyClass` class and following line

```
node.visitContents(this);
```

starts class contents processing. If we take a look at the source code of this method:

```
public void visitContents(GroovyClassVisitor visitor) {
    // now let's visit the contents of the class
    for (PropertyNode pn : getProperties()) {
        visitor.visitProperty(pn);
    }

    for (FieldNode fn : getFields()) {
        visitor.visitField(fn);
    }

    for (ConstructorNode cn : getDeclaredConstructors()) {
        visitor.visitConstructor(cn);
    }

    for (MethodNode mn : getMethods()) {
        visitor.visitMethod(mn);
    }
}
```

> Source: [src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode.java#L1066-L108](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/ClassNode.java#L1066-L1083)

we will see that it analyses and process class properties, fields, constructors and methods. At this phase it resolves all types defined for these elements. It sees that there are two properties `m1` and `m2` with types `MyOuter` and `MyOuter.MyInner` accordingly, and it executes `visitor.visitProperty(pn);` for them. This method executes the one we are looking for - `resolve()`

```
private boolean resolve(ClassNode type, boolean testModuleImports, boolean testDefaultImports, boolean testStaticInnerClasses) {
    resolveGenericsTypes(type.getGenericsTypes());
    if (type.isResolved() || type.isPrimaryClassNode()) return true;
    if (type.isArray()) {
        ClassNode element = type.getComponentType();
        boolean resolved = resolve(element, testModuleImports, testDefaultImports, testStaticInnerClasses);
        if (resolved) {
            ClassNode cn = element.makeArray();
            type.setRedirect(cn);
        }
        return resolved;
    }

    // test if vanilla name is current class name
    if (currentClass == type) return true;

    String typeName = type.getName();

    if (genericParameterNames.get(typeName) != null) {
        GenericsType gt = genericParameterNames.get(typeName);
        type.setRedirect(gt.getType());
        type.setGenericsTypes(new GenericsType[]{ gt });
        type.setGenericsPlaceHolder(true);
        return true;
    }

    if (currentClass.getNameWithoutPackage().equals(typeName)) {
        type.setRedirect(currentClass);
        return true;
    }

    return resolveNestedClass(type) ||
            resolveFromModule(type, testModuleImports) ||
            resolveFromCompileUnit(type) ||
            resolveFromDefaultImports(type, testDefaultImports) ||
            resolveFromStaticInnerClasses(type, testStaticInnerClasses) ||
            resolveToOuter(type);
}
```

> Source: [src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L343-L378](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L343-L378)

This method gets executed for both `MyOuter` and `MyOuter.MyInner` classes. It is worth mentioning that class resolving mechanism only checks if given class is available in the classpath and it does not load or parse any classes. That is why `MyOuter` gets recognized when this method reaches `resolveToOuter(type)`. If we take a quick look at its source code we will understand why it works for this class:

```
private boolean resolveToOuter(ClassNode type) {
    String name = type.getName();

    // We do not need to check instances of LowerCaseClass
    // to be a Class, because unless there was an import for
    // for this we do not lookup these cases. This was a decision
    // made on the mailing list. To ensure we will not visit this
    // method again we set a NO_CLASS for this name
    if (type instanceof LowerCaseClass) {
        classNodeResolver.cacheClass(name, ClassNodeResolver.NO_CLASS);
        return false;
    }

    if (currentClass.getModule().hasPackageName() && name.indexOf('.') == -1) return false;
    LookupResult lr = null;
    lr = classNodeResolver.resolveName(name, compilationUnit);
    if (lr!=null) {
        if (lr.isSourceUnit()) {
            SourceUnit su = lr.getSourceUnit();
            currentClass.getCompileUnit().addClassNodeToCompile(type, su);
        } else {
            type.setRedirect(lr.getClassNode());
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> Source: [src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L725-L751](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L725-L751)

When Groovy class loader tries to resolve `MyOuter` type name it reaches

```java
lr = classNodeResolver.resolveName(name, compilationUnit);
```

which locates script with a name `MyOuter.groovy` and it creates a `SourceUnit` object associated with this script file name. It is simply something like saying *"OK, this class is not in my classpath at the moment, but there is a source file I can see that once compiled it will provide a valid type of name `MyOuter`"*. This is why it finally reaches:

```java
currentClass.getCompileUnit().addClassNodeToCompile(type, su);
```

where `currentClass` is an object associated with `MyClass` type - it adds this source unit to `MyClass` compilation unit, so it gets compiled with the `MyClass` class. And this is the point where resolving

```
MyOuter m1
```

class property ends.

In the next step it picks `MyOuter.MyInner m2` property and it tries to resolve its type. Keep in mind - `MyOuter` got resolved correctly, but it didn't get loaded to the classpath, so it's static inner class does not exist in any scope, yet. It goes through the same resolving strategies as `MyOuter`, but any of them works for `MyOuter.MyInner` class. And this is why [`ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail()`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/ResolveVisitor.java#L323-L327) eventually throws this compilation exception.

### Workaround

OK, so we know what happens, but is there anything we can do about it? Luckily, there is a workaround for this problem. You can run your program and load `MyClass` successfully only if you load `MyOuter` class to Groovy script engine first:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine;

public class TestGroovyScriptEngine {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        final File myGroovySourceDir = new File("C:/MyGroovySourceDir");

        final URL[] urls = { myGroovySourceDir.toURL() };
        GroovyScriptEngine groovyScriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngine(urls,
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        groovyScriptEngine.getGroovyClassLoader().loadClass("MyOuter");

        Class<?> clazz = groovyScriptEngine.getGroovyClassLoader().loadClass("MyClass");
    }
}
```

Why does it work? Well, semantic analysis of `MyOuter` class does not cause any problems, because all types are known at this stage. This is why loading `MyOuter` class succeeds and it results in Groovy script engine instance knows what `MyOuter` and `MyOuter.MyInner` types are. So when you next load `MyClass` from the same Groovy script engine it will apply different resolving strategy - it will find both classes available to the current compilation unit and it wont have to resolve `MyOuter` class based on its Groovy script file.

### Debugging

If you want to examine this use case better it is worth to run a debugger and see analyze what happens at the runtime. You can create a breakpoint at line 357 of `ResolveVisitor.java` file for instance, to see described scenario in action. Keep in mind one thing though - `resolveFromDefaultImports(type, testDefaultImports)` will try to lookup `MyClass` and `MyOuter` classes by applying default packages like `java.util`, `java.io`, `groovy.lang` etc. This resolve strategy kicks in before `resolveToOuter(type)` so you have to patiently jump through them. But it is worth it to see and get a better understanding about how things work. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for writing down all this detail :-)